# Don't call callback block after exiting view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, afnetworking, block

When I build my app, I create a Class called NetEngine to manage all the network request. But I find that after I quit a view controller which use NetEngine, I still call the success or failure block.

viewcontroller:

```
    [[NetEngine engine] GET:httpUrl success:^(id responseObject) {
         //some code here
         //It's still called after I quit viewctroller
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
         //some code here
         //It's still called after I quit viewctroller
    }];
```

NetEngine:

```
typedef void(^SuccessBlock) (id responseObject);
typedef void(^FailureBlock) (NSError *error);

@interface NetEngine ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) AFHTTPSessionManager *httpManager;

@end

@implementation NetEngine

+ (NetEngine *)engine {
    static NetEngine *_sharedEngengine = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedEngengine = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return _sharedEngengine;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _httpManager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BZTVBaseServerPath]];
        [_httpManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"accept"];
        _httpManager.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
        _httpManager.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4;
        [_httpManager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:10.0];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)GET:(NSString *)URLString success:(SuccessBlock)successBlock failure:(FailureBlock)failureBlock {
    // some thing about cache

    [_httpManager GET:encodeUrl parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {
        [[self defaultCache] setObject:responseObject forKey:cacheKey];
        if (successBlock) {
            successBlock(responseObject);
        }
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        if (isCache) {            
            if (successBlock) {
                successBlock([[self defaultCache] objectForKey:cacheKey]);
            }
        }
        if (failureBlock) {
            failureBlock(error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: because the network call is asynchronous and you never know when the url returns the response. You need to hnadle the incoming response! Before quitting the view controller check for the valid response, if it's available quit the vc, else wait for the response!

Comment: @TejaNandamuri You're right, but would you get me some more advise? Or some articles about how to handle the incoming response? Thanks a lot

Comment: I think there won't be any posts regarding this. This all depends on your requirements.You should provide more info about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to cancel the network call when you quit your view controller, here's what you have to do :

Create a `cancel` `BOOL` variable

Add a `viewWillDisappear` method :

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    cancel = YES;
}
```

Check if cancel is YES in callback method :

```
   [[NetEngine engine] GET:httpUrl success:^(id responseObject) {
         //some code here
         //It's still called after I quit viewctroller
         if (!cancel) {
            //do what you have to do
         }
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
         //some code here
         //It's still called after I quit viewctroller
         if (!cancel) {
            //do what you have to do
         }
    }];
```

Comment: Glad to have helped buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation: "Blocks are a language-level feature added to C, Objective-C and C++, which allow you to create distinct segments of code that can be passed around to methods or functions as if they were values".  So, the block itself is an object, which means it has a lifecycle that's not dependent on the object that created it.

If you don't want `NetEngine` to use the code you've given to it, you need a way of passing it that information when you "quit" the view controller.

Basically:

```
[[NetEngine engine] GET:httpUrl success:^(id responseObject) {
    // if the view controller still wants me to do this {
       //some code here
    // }
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    // if the view controller still wants me to do this {
       //some code here
    // }
}];
```

Comment: You're completely right! And @Anthonin get me the way to solve it!